# is there a way to do it by css and suitable for IE,Firefox?

Tags: html, css

[image]

when the mouse hovers on the text. the white rounded corner appears as the text's background. is there a way to get that by css? and how to slice the  rounded corner background. thank you

Comment: What browsers do you care to support? If you are being *progressive*, you could do this with just CSS. Or allow IE to no have rounded corners...

Comment: i want  it could support IE, how should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic technique is [CSS Sliding Doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/), but now you can use some CSS 3 magic to get the same effect.

```
a {
    color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
    color: #222;    
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Here's a working example at JSBin: http://jsbin.com/acizer

Comment: @zhuanzhou - You're right, it doesn't work in IE8 and below. The question is, how important are rounded corners to your design? Can your visitors use the site without them? If it really is important, then use the CSS Sliding Doors technique I linked to at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform rounded-corner css styling by applying the following attributes:

```
.rounded-corners :hover{
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: here is a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/n5csK/) that show the effect in action

Comment: but under IE. there is no effect.

Comment: for IE8+, this solution will work. for IE7 and below, see this page http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll want to use the :hover selector to make the background appear and disappear, and the border-radius, -moz-border-radius and -webkit-border-radius attributes to make the corners rounded.